# how to make light pass through a mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I see in real world some time light pass through our ears and nose,i wanted to know how to make light pass through a mesh in blender cycles?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/how-can-i-make-a-translucent-material-on-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38037/translucent-shadow-ceramic-material

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24888/3127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the sub surface scattering shader (SSS). or the faster and less accurate translucency shader.

Here is Suzanne with a SSS shader applied, and a very bright light behind her:

[image]
[image]

The small scale causes the light to spread less far within the object. I set the radius to 1.0,0.6,0.6 to give the light the red cast.

[image]

Comment: Can you share you share your .blend file i am new to blender i don't know how to add light like you did?

Comment: @Hashir Sure, here it is: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/510/

Comment: Thanx buddy,i really appereciate it